# plot bifurcation diagram in python using Sympy

Tags: python, numpy, plot, sympy, differential-equations

I was looking at a cookbook recipe by Cyrille Rossant on plotting a bifurcation diagram of a chaotic dynamical system. He uses straight numpy to calculate the solution, but I was wondering how to plot this same solution using SymPy? I am really interested in using SymPy to plot bifurcation diagrams if I can. Cyrille uses the logistic equation for the form below. Note that he also plots the lyapunov exponent as well.

```
f_r(x) = rx(1-x)
```

The recursive relation used to solve and plot this equation is:

```
x_{n+1}^{(r)} = f_r(x_{n}^{(r)}) = rx_{n}^{(r)}(1 - x_{n}^{(r)})
```

The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline #for the ipython notebook

# Define the logistic function

def logistic(r, x):
    return(r*x*(1-x))

# Now feed the function our data.

n = 10000
r = np.linspace(2.5, 4.0, n)
iterations = 1000
last = 100

## initialize the system

x = 1e-5*np.ones(n)

# first we initialize the lyapunov vector
lyapunov = np.zeros(n)

# now we simulate the system and plot the diagram

plt.subplot(211)
for i in range(iterations):
    x = logistic(r,x)

## we compute the partial sum of the lyapunov exponent

lyapunov += np.log(abs(r-2*r*x))

#we display the bifurcation diagram
if i >= (iterations - last):
    plt.plot(r,x, ',k', alpha=0.02)
plt.xlim(2.5,4)
plt.title("Bifurcation diagram")

# We display the Lyapunov exponent
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(r[lyapunov < 0], lyapunov[lyapunov< 0]/iterations, ',k', alpha=0.01)
plt.plot(r[lyapunov >= 0], lyapunov[lyapunov>= 0]/iterations, ',k',   
alpha=0.25)
plt.xlim(2.5,4)
plt.ylim(-2,1)
plt.title("Lyapunov Exponent")
```

Again, I would like to convert this code to use SymPy instead.

Comment: I would define the logistic equation symbolically, compute the Lyapunov exponent directly from the definition, and do the numerical calculations as you do now, except use `sympy.lambdify` to convert the symbolic expressions into numeric ones that can be evaluated with numpy and plotted with matplotlib.

Comment: Great. I will try that. If I can get it to work, I will post the results here. Do you have a gallery of examples for sympy on github or something? I can always contribute examples up there too via PR.

Comment: I would look at the [docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html). Most of the functions have examples in their docstrings. I would also recommend reading the tutorial if you are new to SymPy.